# OPEN FOAM con MPI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl, cluster, mpi

```bash
master@serverA:~/OpenFOAM/master-9/run/motorBike$ mpirun -np 8 -hostfile machines #snappyHexMesh -parallel
#--> FOAM FATAL ERROR :
#   Could not find mandatory etc entry (mode=ugo)
#  '--> FOAM FATAL ERROR :
# Could not find mandatory etc entry (mode=ugo)
#   'controlDict'
#--> FOAM FATAL ERROR :
#  Could not find mandatory etc entry (mode=ugo)
#   'controlDict'
#--> FOAM FATAL ERROR :
#  Could not find mandatory etc entry (mode=ugo)
#   'controlDict'

#controlDict'



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
#a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
#the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

#  Process name: [[63183,1],5]
#  Exit code:    1
#
```

Mi error al intentar realizar en cluster de ubuntu server con las mismas configuraciones en ambos lados, alguna sugerencia de los errores, ya que al intentar realizar el snappyHexMesh con el esclavo recien reiniciado intenta realizar el procedimiento y al final manda el mismo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL problema de esto parece estar en cómo ejecutas OpenFOAM. Este y otros tantos problemas se pueden serolver corriendo OpenFOAM desde la carpeta correcta.

Después de que instalaste OpenFOAM, asegúrate de crear un directorio en tu carpeta de usuario que se llame `OpenFOAM` con un subdirectorio llamado `run`, como [se describe en la documentación](https://openfoam.org/download/9-ubuntu/). Para correr uno de los casos en el tutorial, cópialo de la carpeta tutoriales en tu instalación y muévelo a este `~/OpenFOAM/run` para que lo corras DESDE AHÍ.

Tomado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322683/236345)

Más info [en esta discusión](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/issues/2296#note_55349)

Comment: Al revisar los dos equipos tanto maestro y esclavo estos mismos comparten la carpeta OpenFOAM/usr/run/motorbike, al ingresar los comandos blockMesh y decomposepar los ejecuta sin problemas, al intentar unir o compilar por medio de MPI e ingresar htop en el esclavo este logra mostrar por pocos segundos el proceso pero en el nodo maestro sigue mandando el mismo error